# Include all my python libraries to the exe generated by py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, py2exe, continuum

**I want to include all python libraries and dependencies that my python.exe uses to compile and run my programm on my computer**, into the exe Generated by py2exe,
I want that because **py2exe** **.exe* generated is still returning errors and aborts,

Thank you

**Here libraries that I used in my programm:**

```
from Tkinter import *  # POUR L'interface graphique
import tkFileDialog  # POUR l'ouverture d'
import csv
import ttk
import Tix as tix
import re  # regular exprun fichier
import tkMessageBox  # POUR un messageboxe pour quitter le programme
import py2exe, sys, os
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
import datetime as dt
import pygal
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from datetime import datetime as time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
```

**And here my setup.exe script:**

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import os.path

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

sys.argv.append('py2exe')
"""
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': { 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "D:\Users\u156726\PycharmProjects\SFR_APP\SFR_APP_BIG_DATA.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
"""
import matplotlib
import glob

setup(console=['D:\Users\u156726\PycharmProjects\SFR_APP\SFR_APP.py'],options={
               'py2exe': {
                          'packages' :  ['matplotlib', 'pytz'],

                          }
                },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

py2exe offers 'options' parameter to define a list of packages to include or exclude. When there are packages missing you can force py2exe to bundle those packages into the exe.

Review to [docs](http://www.py2exe.org/) for more informations about all the options.

```
includes = ['matplotlib', 'numpy', 'Tkinter', 'tcl', 'Tkconstants', ... ]
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'curses', 'pywin.debugger', 'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs' ]
packages = []
dll_excludes = []

setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 0,
                          "optimize": 0,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 1,
                          "dist_dir": ".",
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                         }
              },
    console=...,
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Maurice, So I am using Windows64 and it causes problem with budle-files1
"error: bundle-files 1 not yet supported on win64"

Comment: Then dont bundle :) I was just copy-n-pasting what i am using since years, you may need to adjust to your needs.

Comment: It still retruning errors like: 
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 1131, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 965, in rc_params
  File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 815, in matplotlib_fname
  File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 320, in wrapper
  File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 718, in _get_data_path_cached
  File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 713, in _get_data_path
RuntimeError: Could not find the matplotlib data files