# Could not load python library

Tags: python, windows, fatal-error, py2exe

At last I finished a my code in Python and converted it to .exe file using py2exe. Program works correctly at my personel computer but when I try it at my office, I got a fatal error: "Could not load python library".
Both computers have the same version of Python and I am sure that I carried all files. Just my pc is Windows 10 and the other one is Windows 7. Could you please help me?

Comment: Maybe adding libraries manually will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940863

Comment: This makes sense, Dudnikof thank you! But I'm not sure how to include some of the libraries. Lines on this topic in my current setup file is as follows:

includes = ["tkinter", "sys", "ttk", "Pandas", "docx", "Document", "Pt", "WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH",  "lxml._elementpath"]
setup(console=['Combobox.py'],
      data_files = Mydata_files,
      options={"py2exe": {"compressed": 0,
                         "includes": includes,
                         "unbuffered": True,
                         "optimize": 2,
                         "bundle_files": 1,
                         }})

Comment: Is it possible that one of the computers is 64-bit and the other not? `py2exe` can't do cross-compilation. Also, the section in the documentation called *When things go wrong* has specific advice about targeting Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you, Boargules but both computers are 64-bit. I'll look to the  When things go wrong section.